# What kind of a building is at the Over There Fringe HQ?

Tags: fringe

During the transition effect which shows us that the story line switched to another Universe, it is very easy to spot a big difference between the Fringe HQ *here* and *there*. Specifically, there is a different building on the other side which somewhat resembles a Roman arena.

What kind of a building is that? Was it a proposed project which was never finished (in actual real life Boston)? Or was it just something that writers made up to stand out and look obviously different so that we could more easily identify which universe we are watching (like airships and the bronze colored statue)?

Comment: Over There Fringe HQ is in New York, as Boston is, well, unavailable.

Comment: @SWeko: Ah, so the transition is city-wise as well as universe-wise.

Comment: @GoranJovic: Nah, the transition remains fixed in temporal and spatial co-ordinates; only the universe changes. (heh, "only")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd assumed it was [Madison Square Garden](http://maps.google.co.uk/maps?um=1&ie=UTF-8&q=madison%20square%20garden&fb=1&gl=uk&hq=madison%20square%20garden&ei=alB5T4W3FZTv8QO82o2zDQ&sa=X&oi=local_group&ct=image&ved=0CCIQtgM) in New York.

Comment: MSG is not the building that is shown for the alternate universe Fringe HQ, it's the Vancouver Public Library as answered by Fringe Watcher

Answer (score 4):

The exterior shots of the Fringe Division headquarters in the alternate universe are actually of the Vancouver Public Library.
http://www.greenroofs.com/projects/pview.php?id=29

Comment: Correct. This building was also featured on Battlestar Galactica on the planet Caprica.